# Example of a Young's function under Lorentz-Shimogaki condition

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-spaces, orlicz-spaces

I am reading about convolution operators and Orlicz spaces. And I would like to contract some example and stuck at some point.

Let $\Psi(t)=\int_0^t\psi(s)$ be a Young's function. Then, $\Psi$ satisfies the Lorentz-Shimogaki condition if
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\Psi(st)}{v(t)^2}\psi(t)dt< \infty.
$$
Denote $\rho_{\Psi}=\frac{1}{\Psi^{-1}(t^{-1})}$ by $Q(t)=\int_0^tg$. One has $L_{\Psi}(R_+)=M(g)=\{f \in M_{+}(R_+): \int_0^tf^*\leq C\int_0^tg=CQ(t)\}$. Hence, if $\Phi(t)=\int_0^t\phi$ is a Young's function and $T_k: L_{\Psi}(R^n)\to L_{\Phi}(R^n)$ if
$$
\int_{R_+}\Phi(s(Qk^{**}+S_{k^*}g))<\infty. \quad (1)
$$

Given $\psi(s)=e^{-1/s}$, when $s<<1$ and $\psi(s)=e^s$, when $s>>1$, investigate when (1) holds for $\Phi(t)=\int_0^t\log(1+s)ds$.